# Dell with Ubuntu pre-installed - no bootable devices!

Tags: dell

The laptop is 4 months old hardly used. Came with Ubuntu. It did an update 3 days ago then rebooted and now it can't see any bootable device. Dell can't help!

Comment: Dell can and should help if Ubuntu was factory installed. Model, Ubuntu version?

Comment: This is way too little information for providing a working solution ... but I guess that you can solve the problem by just booting into BIOS and selecting the correct boot loader : `grubx64.efi` if you have Secure Boot disabled and `shimx64.efi`if you have Secure Boot enabled. :)

Answer (score 0):

Agree with netbox.  The quickest way to see what's going on is to go into the BIOS and see what the device boot order is.  Assuming that the HDD/SDD with Ubuntu is in the boot device list, you could have a problem with something in /boot of the boot device could be defective.  You could try booting from a LiveCD. If that works it will give you access to the boot device directory structure so you can look around.

As previously noted you have not provided sufficient information to troubleshoot this problem.  Could be a bad/corrupted boot device, a BIOS problem or any number of other things.